# How to use Euler's method to program a periodic function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Euler's method I have made the code to find the approximation for the logistic growth equation

```html
def Euler(h,N):
    import numpy as np
    K = 12; r = 0.43; Po = 1;

#defining dP/dt as a function f(P)
   

    for n in range(N+1): #n=0 as index for P[0], then 1<=n<=N

        P = np.append(P,Pn)
    return P[N] #return the last computed value in P

Euler(0.1,5)
```

However for my next assignment (t)=12+2.5sin(t/12), where K is a periodic function. I need some guidance on how I should do this my attempt is below

```html
import numpy as np
from math import sin

def Euler2(h,N): 
    r = 0.43; 
    Po = 1;
#defining dP/dt as a function f(P)
    #initializing P with Po
    for n in range(N+1):
       
    return P[N] #return the last computed value in P

Euler2(0.1,100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some modifications in your code:

- Initialize the `P` before the for loop
- Name the lambda function for `k` as `kfunc` (or other name of your choice)

---

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin

def Euler2(h,N): 
    r = 0.43
    Po = 1
    P = np.array([Po])
    for n in range(N+1):
        kfunc = lambda k:12 + 2.5 *sin(n/12)
        f = lambda P: r*P*(1-P/kfunc(n))
        Pn = P[n] + h*f(P[n]) #euler
        P = np.append(P,Pn)
    return P[N] #return the last computed value in P

Euler2(0.1,100)
# 10.932593954891473
```